# Extracting slopes and intercepts from splines2 results

Tags: r, piecewise

I was trying to teach myself the math behind what produces the slope and intercept of a segmented variable in the segmented package using the plant data set. My plan was to run a model through the segmented package, produce the slopes and intercept using the slope and intercept commands and compare to summary output to the summary output of splines2 package.

That stated, can anyone tell me how I can mimic the `slope` and `intercept` function of the `segmented` package in the `splines2` package with the model2 object?

```
library(splines2)
library(segmented)

x <- as.factor(rnorm(1:50))
y <- (rnorm(1:100)*.5)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))


model <- glm(y~x, data = data)
summary(model)          
model2<- glm(y ~ bSpline(x, degree = 1, knots = c(10,40)), data = data)
summary(model2)

model3 <- segmented(model, seg.Z = ~x, psi = list(x = c(10,40)))
summary(model3)
slope(model3)
intercept(model3)
```

Comment: do you mean how to extract the slope and intercept values from, say, `model2`?

Comment: Yes.  I will edit the post to specify that.  Thank you.

Comment: you could just pull out the coefficients from the model2 summary: `summary(model2)$coefficients`?

Comment: Those are the orthogonal coefficients (I believe).  If you do `summary(model3)` you'll notice that those are different from `slope(model3)` because the `summary` in that shows the orthogonal as well.